# How to run codeigniter(HMVC) inside wordpress folder

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter

Anybody have install codeigniter(HMVC) within wordpress.

I am trying to install codeigniter(HMVC) inside wordpress folder.

my codeigniter is work on Virtual host can it possible to run codeigniter within wordpress setup with codeigniter is work on virtual host.

Any suggestion.

Comment: Its possible if not restricted by the server

Comment: Which path i have to set ?

Comment: Just try this plugin...http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-code-igniter/

Comment: Just edit the .htaccess and Only you want to give the path to go

Comment: @Kango can you go to the path say www.yourwordpresssite.com/yourcodeigniterfolder

Comment: i have run setup by using www.yourwordpresssite.com/yourcodeigniterfolder/renderfolder/index.php RenderFolder is my document root. how can i skip renderFolder/index.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very easy. Here is step by step process.
First see the structure.

[image]

You can see it is inside wordpress directory. Next Add this in `index.php` of codeigniter

```
require_once('../wp-load.php');
```

And finally to avoid conflict between Wordpress and Codeigntier's `site_url` function add this file in codeigniter/application/core as `MY_url_helper.php`

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))  exit('No direct script access allowed');

if (!function_exists('ci_site_url')) {
    function ci_site_url($uri = '')
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        return $CI->config->site_url($uri);
    }
}

if (!function_exists('ci_base_url')) {
    function ci_base_url($uri = '')
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        return $CI->config->base_url($uri);
    }
}
```

Now when you use `site_url()` it will refer to wordpress `site_url()` and 
`ci_site_url()` it will refer to codeigniter's `site_url`. 
And now when you need to access codeigniter try this.

```
`http://localhost/wordpress/codeigniter/index.php/mycontroller/mymethod`
```

Hope it is easy to set up and helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply.i am using HMVC for codeigniter can it be same for HMVC.

Comment: Sure you just need to test

Comment: you can remove index.php as you remove for a normal application by setting `.htaccess`.For this there are many methods you can search on google.

Answer (score 0):

Codeignetor can run OK in every directory if server allows to install on that directory.
If its not working please confirm the security settings from server.

Comment: Codeignetor can run OK in every directory if server allows to install on that directory.
If its not working please confirm the security settings from server.

Comment: by using this my ajax function is not working. it gives 404 not found.